# Can I store a cloned worksheet as a new Excel file with Apache POI?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I cloned a worksheet and made changes to it.  Now I want to store it as a new Excel file.  How can I do that? I looked thought the methods of Workbook and Worksheet and could not find anything that would let me do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(newFilePath);
wb.write(fileOut);

where wb is a Workbook